# Jmeter: To login multiple times and hitting multiple URLS

Tags: performance, testing, load, jmeter

I am novice in Jmeter, just started to know its inner functionality. I am stuck in a problem. I have to hit multiple urls (only search id) is changed so in "HTTP Request" i have placed "/build-4.4.10.0/?earchId=${ID}&Application=sc&IsSearchLink=TRUE"

I am providing session key and that search id through csv file. Problem is though its going to the link but redirecting it to login page, and i do not know how to create users on run time and assign to that each URL.

I have 200+ URLS, what should i do, please guide

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your application needs any login authentication and/or cookies, then you will need to add the Cookie manager for maintaining the session, else application will not be able to maintain a session and it will throw the user out of the application, then redirecting it to the login page.

You can refer to the below mentioned links for more information about cookie manager.

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13966/jmeter-http-cookie-manager/13975#13975

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager

Comment: The problem is I have 200 URLs and each URL have to login from each separate email and password, for URL i am giving the auth key and session id along with that serach id in CSV_DataSet and that part is working fine. Now i have to assign each URL to each individual login session, how can i do that? How to record a session of login and assign to an individual URL. Please guide